# Run macro automatically

Tags: python, excel, automation, vba

I have many xlsm files that I create from an existing xlsm file and add to it data from csv using python.
every file has a macro that need to be run (keyshortcut: ctrl+q)
Is there a way to make it run automatically for every file and save the file after the macro was running?

Thanks!

Comment: Read about [Workbook Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook_events.aspx). Especially `BeforeClose` and `BeforeSave`.

Comment: I didn't understand how it can help me..

Comment: You can write macros that run when some Events in Excel occurs. More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh211482(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!!
I changed the name of my macro to "Auto_open" and now it makes it when I open the file.

Thanks All!

Comment: If you were to use the suggestion of using `BeforeClose` and/or `BeforeSave` you would avoid having to save and close the file after adding the data, then reopening the file to run the macro, then saving and closing the file again.